# How to import a file on open?

Tags: import

How do I set Blender to automatically import a model such as an .OBJ (using the appropriate importer based on the file extension and default options) into the default startup scene when I double click the file in Windows?

Comment: Just append the file from file menu

Comment: Avoiding the file menu is specifically the point of this question. When you have lots of models in different formats and you're looking for the right one, it's infuriating to navigate to them through blender's file dialog when you have already found it in Explorer.